# Searching an array for certain number of integers greater than one integer

Tags: java, arrays, search, methods

I have written this method to find the number of values that are greater than a specific value in an array and it works with arrrays that have positive integers but when I tried this test case it failed.

```
public static int numGreater(int[] a, int val) {
      if (a == null || a.length == 0) {

         throw new IllegalArgumentException();         
      }



      int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
      Arrays.sort(copy);

      int answer = 0;

      int nearest = copy[0];
      for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {

         if (Math.abs(nearest - val) > Math.abs(copy[i] - val)) {

            nearest = copy[i]; 
            answer = (copy.length - 1) - i;
         }       
      }         


      return answer;
   }
```

Here is the test case I ran with JUnit.

```
int z[] = {-5,-2,0,4,8,15,50};


@Test public void numGreaterTest1() {

      Assert.assertEquals(7, Selector.numGreater(z, -99));

}
```

Any ideas on where I went wrong?

Comment: Yes sorry should have definitely put that in tag.

Comment: Why to bother with such algorithm? Wouldn't it be easier just to run an array and build new array consisting only bigger values?

Comment: I am extremely new to java so i apologize for the method. Could you elaborate on your method for the solution? This is for practice from school so its not very practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int numGreater(int[] a, int val) {
      if (a == null || a.length == 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();         
      }

      int answer = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         if (a[i]>val) {
            answer++;
         }       
      }         


      return answer;
   }
```

Comment: a is not necessarily sorted, so you need to sort it before, that is why he is using copy. Also the return value should be a.length - answer.

Comment: Wow I definitely over thought this. I see that it is more of a matter of sorting than searching.