# Java: Compare a value with an array; Getting the first 3 numbers bigger that the value

Tags: java, arrays

I have a number `x=27` and an array of values `int[] y=[15,20,25,30,35,40,45]`.

How can I compare the two in order to get the first 3 numbers from the array that are bigger than x?

I guess a for loop needs to be used here but I'm a beginner so this is beyond me.

Comment: Consider making the problem more simple first: write something to pick out the first number from the array bigger than x. And you've missed out the most important criterion of all: is the array sorted?

Comment: is your array is sorted ?? or any random array you get (un-sorted)??

Comment: Welcome to SO! You are expected to put in a minimal amount of effort first and then ask for help when you get stuck. Otherwise, people here would do more than just help, they would solve the problem for you! The way your question is currently posed, you're not likely to get much help here, sorry.

Comment: simple google search could have given you many SO links with similar kind of questions. [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558397/how-to-find-numbers-in-an-array-that-are-greater-than-less-than-or-equal-to-a), [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580623/searching-an-array-for-certain-number-of-integers-greater-than-one-integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a working solution using arrays:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 27;
        int[] y = {15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45};
        int[] result = new int[3];
        int z = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            if(y[i] > x && z < 3) {
                result[z] = y[i];
                z++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result[0] + " " + result[1] + " " + result[2]); //Print 30 35 40
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is sorted and contains no duplicates (as is the case in the example given), you can get this result out quickly using a binary search:

```
int pos = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(
    y,
    0/*inclusive as per function spec*/,
    y.length/*exlusive as per function spec*/,
    x 
);
if (pos >= 0){
    // x is found at position 'pos', but we want elements greater than this.
    ++pos;
} else {
    int i = -pos - 1; // this is where x would be inserted to preserve sortedness
    pos = i + 1;
}
// ToDo - your elements are at `pos`, `pos + 1`, and `pos + 2`,
// subject to your not running over the end of the array `y`.
```

Comment: Indeed and this answer is little more than using a standard (and therefore well-documented) function from the Java library.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int[] y={15,30,29,30,35,40,45};
    int x=27;

    for(int i = 0,index = 3; i < y.length; i++){
        if(i < index && y[i] > x){
            System.out.print(y[i]+" ");

        }

    }
```

output:

> 30 29

Answer (score 0):

Fascinating how everybody sticks to loops... Stream-based, we have 2016 after all:

```
    int[] y = {15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45};
    int x = 17;
    IntStream.of(y).filter(v -> v > x).limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);
```